Solve in solving equation system
I have the following problem:
I have a system of equations specifically consisting of 56 equations, with 34 coefficients to be determined, in simplified form:
(a+2b-c)A[something]==0
(b+3d-c)A[something else]==0
...

Where A is some operator. Now, I want to use Solve to solve this system of equations:
Solve[(a+2b-c)A[something]==0&&(b+3d-c)A[something else]==0&&...,{a,b,c,d,....}]

However, this takes quite a long time because the expressions are somewhat complicated and lengthy.
I'm not exactly sure how the algorithm works and whether Solve[] only looks at the expressions in the parentheses or also works with the operators A[], which might lead to incorrect expressions because I defined the effects of A myself, so Mathematica might not know how to handle the A's properly.
In summary, my question is:
Does the Solve[] algorithm only interact with the expressions within parentheses, or does it do something else?
If not, is there a simple method to write something similar to Solve[] that leaves the operators A[] alone?
Any opinions and tips on speeding up the process are very welcome.

If you want to get the best answer and help, please include your whole code in the question.

Compare the result from Solve with the result from Reduce. Solve is very good at some categories of problems. Reduce is better at others, but sometimes slower. Start with a small problem that is similar in form to your full problem, see if Reduce can crack it and study the result. Then make a slightly larger problem and repeat. When I don't get an instant solution from MMA for a problem I find it helpful to think "just imagine how much longer this would have taken if I were scratching this out on a piece of paper with a crayon" and I find myself MUCH happier at that point.

Possibly quick experiment to see what happens if "Solve leaves the operators A[] alone" Restart MMA or clear any definitions of A[] and then try Solve or Reduce without defining A[anything]. That hopefully will leave all A[anything] alone and treated as a simple unknown and see if Solve or Reduce can give you a solution containing those unknowns. If that experiment doesn't work then try defining A[_]=1 before your Solve and that will show you a result as if the A[anything] just disappears.
